# Flowchart in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, io

I need to write a prog in Python that accomplishes the following:

Prompt for and accept the input of a number, either positive or negative.
Using a single alternative "decision" structure print a message only if the number is positive.

It's extremely simply, but I'm new to Python so I have trouble with even the most simple things.  The program asks for a user to input a number.  If the number is positive it will display a message. If the number is negative it will display nothing.

```
num = raw_input ("Please enter a number.")

if num >= 0 print "The number you entered is " + num
else:
    return num
```

1. I'm using Wing IDE
2. I get the error "if num >= 0 print "The number you entered is " + num"
3. How do I return to start if the number entered is negative?
4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something is wrong with your IDE if it is not telling you that you have a syntax error.  You need a colon for the `if` clause after 0 and before `print`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def getNumFromUser():
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if num >= 0: 
        print "The number you entered is " + str(num)
    else:
        getNumFromUser()

getNumFromUser()
```

The reason you received an error is because you omitted a colon after the condition of your if-statement. To be able to return to the start of the process if the number if negative, I put the code inside a function which calls itself if the `if` condition is not satisfied. You could also easily use a `while` loop.

```
while True:
    num = input("Please enter a number: ")
    if num >= 0: 
        print "The number you entered is " + str(num)
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inputnum = raw_input ("Please enter a number.")
num = int(inputnum)

if num >= 0:
    print("The number you entered is " + str(num))
```

you don't need the `else` part just because the code is not inside a method/function.

I agree with the other comment - as a beginner you may want to change your IDE to one that will be of more help to you (especially with such easy to fix syntax related errors)

(I was pretty sure, that print should be on a new line and intended, but... I was wrong.)

Comment: Also, `num` is a string. We need to convert it to an int or float for the comparison, `num >= 0`.

Comment: @Marcin: I believe it was one of the problems. I haven't pointed everything - right, but not having print in a new line (& indented properly) was part of the problem, I believe.

Comment: @MaciekTalaska: Actually it doesn't need to be on a new line, as long as the colon is there.

Comment: @A.R.S. ok, thanks for pointing that. I was pretty sure that it should have been on new line, but just checked it... and you're right.

Comment: @MaciekTalaska which IDE would you suggest for a beginner?

Comment: @Chronotope IPython (improved python interactive), Spyder, PyScripter (for Windows only) or Eclipse + PyDev (or Aptana if you want to develop in Ruby as well). These all are free. There is one non-free made by Jetbrains (guys behind IntelliJ Idea, Resharper...): PyCharm.